# azure reserved IP for VM is diffrent than the given

Tags: azure, ip, virtual-machine, reserved

any help appreciated:

I'm a bit confused with the fact that when I add a reserved IP to a cloud service, the IP address matches the one reserved. When I do the same but add an instance IP address to a certain machine, it only adds a random public IP address to the machine, and changes the name accordingly to the one reserved but  the IP address does not matches the one reserved. Any ideas?

This is my reserved IP

```
ReservedIPName       : name
Address              : XX.XX.11.119
Id                   : AA
Label                : sipserver
Location             : West Europe
State                : Created
InUse                : False
```

if I do

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName mycloud -Name vm1inmycloud | Set-AzurePublicIP -PublicIPName ippublic1 | Update-AzureVM
```

It goes ok, but then ippublic1 looks like not in use

```
ReservedIPName       : name
Address              : XX.XX.11.119
Id                   : AA
Label                : sipserver
Location             : West Europe
State                : Created
InUse                : False
```

and the machine has now a public ip address

```
InstanceEndpoints     : {SSH}
InstanceErrorCode     :
InstanceFaultDomain   : 0
InstanceName          : vm1inmycloud
InstanceSize          : Small
InstanceStateDetails  :
InstanceStatus        : ReadyRole
InstanceUpgradeDomain : 0
RoleName              : mycloud
DeploymentID          : BB
IPAddress             : XX.XX.70.17
PublicIPAddress       : XX.XX.1.26
PublicIPName          : name
ServiceName           : mycloud
OperationDescription  : Get-AzureRole
OperationId           : CC
OperationStatus       : Succeeded
```

with the name as the reserved IP but with a different IP, I don't get it!

Regards

Helio

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, did you managed to solve it ?